# is there any way that i can convert EPS file to EMF enhanced meta file into slide using VBA

Tags: vba, import, powerpoint, eps

i was trying to figure out a way using external libraries to do the job, using Imagemagick.

```
Sub ConvertEPS()
  Declare variables for the file paths
  Dim epsFile As String
  Dim pngFile As String

  ' Set the file paths
  epsFile = "F:\123.eps"
  pngFile = "F:\xyz.png"

  ' Call ImageMagick to convert the EPS file to PNG
  Shell "convert.exe " & epsFile & " " & pngFile, vbHide

  ' Insert the PNG image into the active slide
  ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddPicture(pngFile, msoFalse, msoTrue, 0, 0).Select

  ' Clean up by deleting the PNG file
  Kill pngFile

End Sub
```

Comment: Bifore converting it you add it as picture. **Do you see it before trying to export**? I am afraid that EPS format is  not accepted and you have nothing to be exported because of that...

Comment: This is pretty much doomed if it's supposed to work on any recent Windows version of PowerPoint. Microsoft has disabled EPS as an import file format.

Comment: i was trying to figure out a way using external libraries to do the job,

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood that. What's not working right, then?  If you comment out the final "Kill" command, and look at the output folder, is the PNG there or did it not get created?  Or, a strong possibility, you're not giving ImageMagick enough time to create the PNG before trying to import it.

Comment: Iam getting an error, " An error occurred while importing file F:\xyz.png". it seems Imagemagick is not creating PNG file using EPS file. But code is trying to pull something which is not there in directory.  Iam trying same using other library like Ghostscript and Aspose, but no use, getting same error. What could be the issue.?